# openai using python, returned length problem in "text-davinci-002" model

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to use **"text-davinci-002"** model using **"openai"**. The returned text is a single sentence while the same sentence returns a full text in openAI official example.
This is the code used:

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
            model="email to ask for a promotion",
            prompt=userPrompt,
            temperature=0.76
            )
```

The output of this code is:
*Hello [Employer],

I would like to request a promotion*

while the same sentence in OpenAI website [here](https://beta.openai.com/docs/quickstart/introduction) outputs:
*
Hello [Employer],

I would like to request a promotion to the position of [position you want]. I have been with the company for [amount of time] and I feel that I have the experience and qualifications needed for the position.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: The GPT-3 API in its JSON returns a `finish_reason` field (e.g. "stop"); what does that field say for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    
model_name = "text-davinci-002"
prompt = "email to ask for a promotion"

completion = openai.Completion.create(
    model=model_name,
    prompt=prompt,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5,
    max_tokens=150
)

generated_text = completion.choices[0].text
print(generated_text)
```

Model must be a correct model name, in your case "text-davinci-002"